# What is the most efficient way to control and manage task nodes?

Tags: ros, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Mainly, starting a task node if a sensor condition is met, running the task node (sensing, processing, and actuating necessary to complete goal), ending the task upon meeting end condition, and repeating the process for the next task. I am very new to ROS, so any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259222/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-control-and-manage-task-nodes?/) by [mclambchops](https://answers.ros.org/users/30018/mclambchops/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2017-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is normally done as an [action](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib). Your task node will run an action server and wait until the action is requested by another node. After finishing the task, your node will simply wait again until it is used again.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mclambchops](https://answers.ros.org/users/30018/mclambchops/) on 2017-04-13**:
Thank you. Looking into it now.

**Comment by [dmkarage](https://answers.ros.org/users/31032/dmkarage/) on 2018-09-25**:
Could actionlib be used also for different tasks such as navigation and manipulation? For example, patrolling around in a room and once you spot small objects on the ground, pick them up, place them on a table and continue patrolling. Can a behavior like this be implemented with actionlib?